# How can I find the IP address of the machine that created a capture in Wireshark?

Tags: ip-address, wireshark, packet-capture

Basically, I am using [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) looking at captures that have been created previously. How may I find the IP address of the machine that created the capture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guaranteed way as, to capture packets, the user would be in 'promiscuous' mode. This is a state where all packets detected by the interface are captured. Hence, there is no way to determine which packets were destined to the person capturing the packets unless you knew where they lived in the network topology, as then you could make some assumptions that might help (for example, wireless clients would not get packets destined for the Internet sent by wired clients, if connected to the same router).

In addition, if you knew some services running on the capturer's computer you could reasonably conclude the users IP address based on the fact a lot of packets were captured destined for that service at that address.

Comment: The person that has created the capture has left there IP address within it, my task is to find it im just not sure how, if it was to be on there for definite is there no way to filter it to find or some other function to see the "creators" IP?

Comment: Well I have just given you some examples of how you might whittle it down but as I say there is no certainty, although presumably something you know that you haven't shared is enough otherwise this person would not have tasked you with it. Please don't bring your homework questions here.

Comment: Would you say that majority of the bytes would be created by the machine that captured, meaning i could find through stat-ethernet and apply filter on mac address? it is final year coursework but i dont want an answer for the work, just suggestions how to find stuff using wireshark i do enjoy using this program and it is the kind of stuff i want to learn for my future career.

Comment: Not necessarily, the capturing machine in practical cases of packet capturing would generate NO packets of its own. Final year degree coursework? What more can you tell us about the topology of the network the capturing was done in, or any other information.

Comment: yes degree, im studying computer forensics but this is one of my second semester modules (i would rather have spent 3 years on this), with regards to network topology im not really to sure what to tell you, the coursework is basically a large capture of data with various users and a potential attack i have to describe what is happening in the capture, what potential threats there are (I've found port scanning and ping at the moment), the IP of the machine that created the capture and a list of websites that are included in the capture

Comment: all ive found at the moment is that 150.204.48.189 is creating lots of ping requests and trying to access lots of ports in quick succession so this would be my "criminal" apart from that im really novice with this software. we've been asked to do quite a lot with it considering we have only had access to it for 3 weeks.

Comment: Ah I think the case is that this capture has been performed by an admin or is an automated log and since someone found out an attack was performed on the network the point of the logging was to allow them to determine who had been doing the attacking, rather than who was the person doing capturing and then you suddenly get hold of the capture files. :) In which case, your reasoning is sound that the user doing that is most likely trying to mount an attack by exploiting network services on some target machines.

Comment: thanks a lot for your advise today mate, i would leave you rep but it wont allow me yet unfortunately :D great website here though.

Comment: sorry to pester you, i was wondering if you could advise me on what does it mean when the info is stating "who has 150.204.48.112? Tell 150.204.48.5" source shows a mac address and the destination is broadcast, it stumps me every time i see it, is it necessary to include in a report or just trivial information

Comment: That is an ARP request. There is such an attack surface as APR whereby an attacker 'poisons' nodes ARP cache so that people route their data via the attack, allow it to capture data that would otherwise be handled by the router/network gateway.

Answer (score 0):

If the capturing host is sending & receiving traffic over the same interface that it doing the sniffing then you would expect to see very low TCP acknowledgement RTTs from the host's IP address. This is because the RTT timer measures the time between seeing a packet and the corresponding acknowledgement and the host's TCP stack should send the ACK almost instantaneously (unless it is under severe load).

If the RTT is less than ~50 microseconds then it is almost certainly originating from the capturing host.

In Wireshark I would add the [TCP acknowledgement round-trip-time](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html) (tcp.analysis.ack_rtt) filter as a custom column, then sort this column to find the minimum value.

On my machine I see tcp.analysis.ack_rtt times of less than 15usec. I believe that even low-latency networks like InfiniBand will not give host-to-host times this low.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guaranteed way...

But there are some indicators if a packet originats by the computer that was used to capture. This requires that the capture filter did not exclude these packets.

> Background: The packets are captured before they leave the network adapter.

If you see packets that have one of these properties than you have a base for an educated guess:

- The packet is shorter than 64 Bytes, so call [RUNT packets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#RUNT-FRAMES). Small packets are extended automatically by the network controller. So you seldom receive very small packets.
- All IP header checksums are zero. These are adapted during Transmission.

You can configure Wireshark to display these checksum as incorrect in the preferences. Look for other preferences that disable such (false) error indication to extend this list.

Answer (score 0):

## Possible Method

a pretty good way would be to **check the TTL values of IP packets**.

packets sent by the machine the capture was made on should:

- have the sent packet's IP header's source field set to their IP address.
- have the sent packet's IP header's TTL field set to their [OSs default TTL value](http://www.binbert.com/blog/2009/12/default-time-to-live-ttl-values/). *(you'll need to make a guess whcih OS it is if you don't know.)*

[relevant information about TTL from this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live):

> The TTL field is set by the sender of the datagram, and reduced by every router on the route to its destination. If the TTL field reaches zero before the datagram arrives at its destination, then the datagram is discarded

## Example

For example, the capture below was made on a **Windows 10** machine with the address **192.168.1.72**. You can tell because **all the TTLs are 128**.

[image: All the TTLs from 192.168.1.72 are 128, indicating that it is a windows machine and the capture was made on it.]

In contrast, when the filter is set to `ip.dst == 192.168.1.72` you get all kinds of different TTLs, which reinforces that the sender is **192.168.1.72**.

[image: All the TTLs are different, indicating that the capture was not made on these machines]